The Profile attribute does not work from the PyCaret Setup function
The Profile attribute does not work from the PyCaret Setup function. When I run the code it appears
import pycaret
pycaret.__version__

output '3.3.2'
ClassificationSetup = setup(data = data, target = 'class', 
                   session_id=42,
                   profile=True) 

output Loading profile... Please wait!
But the report never appears.
I'm using Python 3.9.19
A report should appear with the information on each variable such as duplicates, nulls, correlations, histograms, etc...

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to images, please type out the relevant details in your question.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
